# Java, invoking methods on objects one after the other (C# style)

Tags: c#, java, syntax, invoke, method-call

I was wondering if Java had a form of this:

```
new Object().methodOne("This is the first method").methodTwo("Second attached method");
new String("Hello World  ").TrimEnd().Split(' ');
```

thank you

Comment: Why not just try it out, and perhaps spare the documentation a glimpse? You could be surprised …

Comment: This is called method chaining.

Comment: One example in the Java API that uses this is `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do this in Java. It depends on the return type of the method.

A particular API may not support this in that methods may not return types that are easily used like this.  But Java most certainly supports accessing instance members of objects without assigning them to a variable.

I think what you might be after is the concept of a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (which can be expressed with Java, of course).

Comment: your right, i have two methods: void setProp1(string val); void setProp2(string val). So the api i want to use I can do Object.setProp1("one"); Object.setProp2("two"); but not both because the second call would be invoked on the void return of setProp1. I wanted to make my array initialization list easy. Oh well, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this sort of thing in Java. For example:

```
class Test {
    public Test method(int x) {
        return this;
    }
    public Test method2(String y) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then, you can:

```
new Test().method(5).method2("test");
```

This kind of interface where you can string method calls together is called a [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). Martin Fowler (who coined the term) actually first demonstrated it using Java.